# pandas substring lookup, to return multiple values (keyword tagging) [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have 2 pandas dataframes:

df1 - contains a column of various phrases:

```
    keyword
    ---
    foo
    bar
    baz
    qux
    quux
    foo bar
    foo baz
```

df2 - contains 1 column with a list of words and columns with categories

```
    keyword         tag1          tag2       
    ---
    foo             abc           def
    bar             123           456
    baz             abc           def
    qux
```

I'm looking for a quick way to assign the tags in `df2` to the phrases in `df1`, such that if the values in `df1['A']` match/contain one or more of the values in `df2['A']`, the corresponding tags in `df2` will be added in new columns to `df1`.

The output should look like this:

```
    keyword         tag1          tag2       
    ---
    foo             abc           def
    bar             123           456
    baz             abc           def
    qux       
    quu
    foo bar         abc,123       def,456
    foo baz         abc           def
    foo bar baz     abc,123       def,456
```

You'll notice in the output above that:

- `qux`'s tags are blank as there are no tags in `df2`
- `quux`'s tags are blank as it has not appeared in `df2`,
- `foobar` has had 2 sets of tags applied,
- each tag has been asssigned only once (see `foobaz` and `foobarbaz`)

The actual dataframes will be much larger (horizontally/vertically). I've searched for answers but haven't found what I need. If you know of anything relevant, please provide links. If you'd like me to clarify anything just say.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured *something* out, along these lines:

```
tags = df2.loc[:,df2.columns.str.contains('tag')].columns # create list of new columns (allows # of columns to vary)

# format tags for potential errors
df2 = df2.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True) # adjust cells containing only whitespace to NaN
df2 = df2.replace(r'^\s+|\s+$', '', regex=True) # remove leading and trailing whitespace
df2 = df2.dropna(subset=tags, how='all').reset_index(drop=True)  # drop ngrams from df2 that have no tags

# add tag columns from d2 to df1
for i in tags:
    df1[i] = [[] for x in range(len(df1))] # create new columns in df1, adding empty list to each cell

# add tags from df2 to df1
cols = len(tags)
for i in tags:
    print(f'\nStarting column "{i}"...') # progress tracker
    groups = df2.groupby(i, as_index=False).aggregate(lambda x : list(x)) # groupby 'tag' column and create list of corresponding keywords (to limit the iterations)
    groups = groups[['keyword',i]]
    groups = groups.dropna(axis=0, how='any') # drop rows with no tags
    rows = len(groups)
    for j in groups.index:
        tag = groups[i][j]
        if tag not in [np.nan, 'nan', '']: # skip empty tags
            print (f'{j+1} of {rows} - {tag}') # progress tracker
            substrings = groups['keyword'][j]
            if len(substrings) > 1:
                substrings = '|'.join(substrings) # create string from list for regex later
            else:
                substrings = substrings[0] # else get element from list as str
            match = df1['keyword'].str.contains(substrings, regex=True, case=False)
            df1.loc[match, i] = df1[i].apply(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x + [tag]))) # 'list(dict.fromkeys())' ensures the resulting list contains only unique values

print('\nFormatting tags...')
for i in tags:
    df1[i] = df1[i].str.join(',') # makes lists into strings separated by ','

print('\nTagging complete')
```

It's not quick and the logic's unlikely to be optimal, but it gets the job done. If anyone has a faster way of achieving the goal please feel free to contribute :)